# HDInsight - ResourceDeploymentFailure

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to create a Hadoop HDInsight cluster (with my free tier). I'm trying to use different then default nodes setup (tried several combinations), but my deployment keeps failing with error message below.

After using the default setup of nodes the deployment successfully finished. Is there some minimum setup (head and worker) nodes type I can use?

```
STATUSMESSAGE
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidDocumentErrorCode",
        "message": "DeploymentDocument 'CsmDocument_2_0' failed the validation. Error: 'VM size 'Standard_D1' provided in the CSM document is invalid or not supported for role 'headnode''"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means we can't use VM size `Standard_D1` to deploy head nodes.

I have reproduce your error, when I try to use `Standard_D2`, get the same error message.

Here a list about **the default virtual machine sizes** for HDInsighr clusters.

[image]
It seems the head node should have 4 cores at least.

More information about the list, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning#default-node-configuration-and-virtual-machine-sizes-for-clusters).

**Note:**

> Free Trial subscriptions are not eligible for limit or quota
>   increases.

For now, Free Trial subscription core limit is **4**, Hadoop will create two head nodes and one data node, at least we need 9 cores,  we **can't** increase the CPU limit to support deploy HDInsight.

If you want to deploy HDInsight, maybe we should upgrade subscription to a Pay-As-You-Go.